# Extract specific part in a column using regex in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Hello I have a dataframe such as

```
COL1 
scaffold_6202_0_5660-8393_+__Apis_cerana
scaffold_27087_2-HSPs_+__Canis_lupus
LBMM01007576.1_2-HSPs_-__Lasius_niger
NW_019416736.1_1_2-HSPs_-__Cattus_felis
KQ415617.1_114142-115354_+__SPO_E
UXGB01011990.1_1481-2897_-__Apis_mellifera
CM010866.1_742312-745306_-__Cuniculus_griseus
scaffold_10628_4264-5914_-__Rattus_rattus 
IDBA_scaffold30_1_30-466_+__SP_A
IDBA_scaffold43_30-466_+__SP_B
```

and I would like to use a regex expression in order to extract only the part between :

`[part to extract]_Number-HSPs_*` **or** if there is not the **HSPs** pattern extract   `[part to extract]_Number*-Number_*`

and save it into a `COL2`
Here I should get :

```
COL1                                          COL2
scaffold_6202_0_5660-8393_+__Apis_cerana      scaffold_6202_0
scaffold_27087_2-HSPs_+__Canis_lupus          scaffold_27087
LBMM01007576.1_2-HSPs_-__Lasius_niger         LBMM01007576.1
NW_019416736.1_1_2-HSPs_-__Cattus_felis       NW_019416736.1_1
KQ415617.1_114142-115354_+__SPO_E             KQ415617.1
UXGB01011990.1_1481-2897_-__Apis_mellifera    UXGB01011990.1
CM010866.1_742312-745306_-__Cuniculus_griseus CM010866.1
scaffold_10628_4264-5914_-__Rattus_rattus     scaffold_10628
IDBA_scaffold30_1_30-466_+__SP_A              IDBA_scaffold30_1
IDBA_scaffold43_30-466_+__SP_B                IDBA_scaffold43
```

So far I succeded to use

```
import re 

df['COL2'] = re.sub(r"_[^0-9]*-Number_", "", df['COL1'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.extract`:

```py
df["COL2"] = df["COL2"].str.extract('(^.*?(?=_[^_-]+-\w+))')
```

### Demo

Comment: I get the error message :  ```ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups```

Comment: The answer should be working, check the demo

Comment: @Grendel Sorry, I left out the mandatory capture group.  Please try it again.

Comment: It works now thank you for your time and help ! :-)

Answer (score 3):

For the example data, you might also match either word characters and dots until the last underscore it can match, as a word character also matches an underscore.

```
^([\w.]+)_
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JZjAXv/1)

```
df['COL2'] = df["COL1"].str.extract(r'^([\w.]+)_')
```

Comment: Very clever, ++